# с++ WINAPI Edit text работает очень криво

Tags: c++, winapi

Начал изучать winapi  в c++ написал простенькую программку которая меняет название окна на то что мы написали в текст боксе:

```
#include <Windows.h>

LRESULT CALLBACK WindowProcedure(HWND, UINT, WPARAM, LPARAM);

void AddMenu(HWND);
void AddControl(HWND);


HWND hEdit;

int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hInst, HINSTANCE hPrewInst, LPSTR args, int ncmdshow)
{
    WNDCLASSW wc = { 0 };
    wc.hbrBackground = (HBRUSH)COLOR_WINDOW;
    wc.hCursor = LoadCursor(NULL, IDC_ARROW);
    wc.hInstance = hInst;
    wc.lpszClassName = L"class";
    wc.lpfnWndProc = WindowProcedure;

    if (!RegisterClassW(&wc))
        return -1;

    CreateWindowW(L"class", L"Window", WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW | WS_VISIBLE, 100, 100, 500, 500, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL);
    MSG msg = { 0 };
    while (GetMessage(&msg, NULL, NULL, NULL))
    {
        TranslateMessage(&msg);
        DispatchMessage(&msg);
    }
    return 0;
}

LRESULT CALLBACK WindowProcedure(HWND hWnd, UINT msg, WPARAM wp, LPARAM lp)
{
    switch (msg)
    {
    case WM_COMMAND:
        switch (wp)
        {
        case 1:
            MessageBeep(MB_SERVICE_NOTIFICATION); break;
        case 2:
            DestroyWindow(hWnd); break;
        case 3:
            wchar_t text[100];
            GetWindowTextW(hEdit, text, 100);
            SetWindowTextW(hWnd, text);
            break;
        }
    case WM_CREATE:
        AddMenu(hWnd);
        AddControl(hWnd);
        break;
    case WM_DESTROY:
        PostQuitMessage(0);
        break;
    default:
        return DefWindowProcW(hWnd, msg, wp, lp);
    }
}

void AddMenu(HWND hWnd)
{
    HMENU hMenu;
    hMenu = CreateMenu();
    HMENU file;
    file = CreateMenu();
    HMENU Sub;
    Sub = CreateMenu();

    AppendMenu(hMenu, MF_POPUP, (UINT_PTR)file, "File");

    AppendMenu(file, MF_STRING, 1, "Open");
    AppendMenu(file, MF_POPUP, (UINT_PTR)Sub, "Sub");

    AppendMenu(file, MF_STRING, 2, "Exit");

    AppendMenu(Sub, MF_STRING, 3, "Change");

    SetMenu(hWnd, hMenu);

}

void AddControl(HWND hWnd)
{
    CreateWindowW(L"Static", L"Enter text: ", WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD | WS_BORDER | SS_CENTER, 200, 100, 100, 20, hWnd, NULL, NULL, NULL);
    hEdit = CreateWindowW(L"Edit", L"...", WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD | WS_BORDER | ES_MULTILINE | ES_AUTOVSCROLL, 200, 152, 100, 50, hWnd, NULL, NULL, NULL);

}
```

По дефолту в текст боксе стоит текст `...` который потом можно изменить. 
По идее я должен изменить текст и в менюшке сверху выбрать File -> Sub -> Change и он должен изменить название моего окна на то что было в текс боксе.
Проблема в том что он ничего не изменяет если я в нем что то пишу и просто остаются теже 3 точки. Но как только выделю эти три точки, сразу появится текст который программа почему то не видит(то есть я меняю название окна но оно меняется не на то что я написал а на три точки).

Однако если из описания этого текст бокса убрать `| ES_MULTILINE | ES_AUTOVSCROLL` то текст редактируется уже нормально, НО меню сверху вообще пропадет будто там его и не было

В чем ошибка у меня, как это пофиксить?

Answer (score 1):

Ваша программа страдает он неопределенного поведения, так как в функция `WindowProcedure` возвращает мусор при обработке всех сообщений вне блока `default`.

Обработка сообщения `WM_COMMAND` тоже неверная. в `wparam` передается два значения - нижние два байта содержат идентификатор контрола, а верхние два байта содержат код оповещения. Вам надо обрабатывать оповещение [`EN_CHANGE`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb761676(v=vs.85).aspx).

Кроме того, следует проверять возвращаемые значения при вызове системных функций. Сейчас у вас все потенциальные ошибки молча игнорируются.

Comment: А как тогда это лучше записать. Я поменял `WM_COMMAND` на `EN_CHANGE` и поле заработало по нормальному, но меню не реагирует на него. То есть все остальные кейсы просто сломались. 
А когда я создал еще один свич специально для 3 кейса то опять текст бокс сломался....

Comment: Нет, обрабатывать надо как раз `WM_COMMAND`, а код `EN_CHANGE` извлекать из `wparam`.

Comment: а можно немного попроще, просто совсем не понимаю как это извлекать? что то типа `if else` надо писать?

Comment: Это описано в документацию по ссылке, которую я привел в ответе.

Comment: так я поэтому и попросил по проще, потому что не понял в этой статье это

Answer (score 1):

В примере неправильно обрабатываются сообщения в оконном обработчике WindowProcedure() и в этом корень зла.

Во-первых, он всегда должен возвращать определенное значение (индивидуальное для каждого сообщения), которое интерпретируется системой соответствующим образом. Смотрите MSDN для каждого сообщения, чтобы понимать смысл возвращаемого значения. В примере добавьте `return 0;` перед выходом из обработчика, чтобы было вот так:

```
    ...
    default: return DefWindowProcW(hWnd, msg, wp, lp);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Во-вторых, ваша секция WM_COMMAND не заканчивается бриком (`break;`). Те `break`, которые в ней имеются, относятся ко вложенным в нее `switch` / `case`. Следовательно, все сообщения WM_COMMAND продолжают выполняться в секции WM_CREATE. Это надо исправить: смотрим в MSDN, что возвращает [WM_COMMAND](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/windows/desktop/ms647591%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). Оно должно возвращать 0, если сообщение было обработано программой. Поэтому в конце WM_COMMAND мы можем поставить `break;` для всех обработанных сообщений (переход на добавленный ранее `return 0` за внешним `switch`). Получится так:

```
    ...
    case 3:
        wchar_t text[100];
        GetWindowTextW(hEdit, text, 100);
        SetWindowTextW(hWnd, text);
        break;
    }
    break;
case WM_CREATE:
    ...
```

В-третьих, в отношении WM_COMMAND в MSDN читаем, что это сообщение комбинированное, может отправляться от меню, от акселераторов и от дочерних элементов управления. Текущий код этого не учитывает. Если lParam содержит 0, то сообщение WM_COMMAND пришло от меню (при HIWORD(wParam)=0) или от акселератора (при HIWORD(wParam)=1). Если lParam не равно 0, то сообщение пришло от дочернего элемента управления. Поэтому часто WM_COMMAND обрабатывают так:

```
case WM_COMMAND:
    if (lParam)
    {
        // Обработка уведомлений от элементов управления
        ...
        // завершение обработки (break; или return 0; или return DefWindowProcW(hWnd, msg, wp, lp); в зависимости от смысла результата) 
    }
    // Обработка наших команд меню и акселераторов (если они есть):
    switch (LOWORD(wParam))
    {
        ...
    }
    break; // переход на `return 0`, т.е. возврат кода "сообщение обработано"
```

В вашем примере, если нет намерений обрабатывать уведомления от элементов управления, а только сообщения от меню, добавьте сразу после case WM_COMMAND:

```
if (lParam) return DefWindowProcW(hWnd, msg, wp, lp);
```

Этой строкой Вы будете передавать все уведомления от дочерних элементов на обработку по умолчанию.